# Почему возникает ошибка "KeyError" ? Python+PrettyTable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять, в чём же ошибка.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = []
x.field_names.append("example")
x.add_row(["Example"])
print(x)
KeyError: 'example'
```

После вызова x возникает ошибка "KeyError", причём возникает она только тогда, когда я добавляю элементы в список x.field_names с помощью методов append, insert и т.д, при ручном же добавлении никаких проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно пользуетесь модулем - для добавления столбцов существует специальный метод `.add_column(...)`:

```
In [24]: x = PrettyTable()

In [25]: x.add_column("col1", [1,2,3])

In [26]: x.add_column("col2", [3,2,1])

In [27]: print(x)
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|  1   |  3   |
|  2   |  2   |
|  3   |  1   |
+------+------+
```

или укажите все столбцы в конструкторе:

```
In [36]: x = PrettyTable(['col1','col2'])

In [37]: x.add_row(['a','b'])

In [38]: x.add_row(['c','e'])

In [39]: print(x)
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|  a   |  b   |
|  c   |  e   |
+------+------+
```